# Lua: Add a table inside a table

Tags: lua

```
local test = {
    {
        Resource = "test",
    },
},
```

How can I add a table inside another table? so it will look like this

```
local test = {
    {
        Resource = "test",
        {
            File = "this is a test",
            Code = "this is a test",
        },
        {
            File = "this is a test",
            Code = "this is a test",
        },
    },
}
```

---

Umm im only writing this because this post is mostly code and therefore have to put more text.
so please ignore this part :) and good new year

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Programming/Tables ?

Comment: The code you've provided works fine, what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: If i should do it in a script so it calculates calculations and puts them into the table. But it need to create a table without overwriting the var Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local test = {
    {
        Resource = "test",
    },
}

for i = 1,2 do
   test[1][i] = {
            File = "this is a test",
            Code = "this is a test",
        }
end
```

or

```
for _ = 1,2 do
  table.insert(test[1], {
            File = "this is a test",
            Code = "this is a test",
        }
end
```